# SQL Server Order By Case - Converting from Date/Time to String?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will allow for the caller to specify if they would like to order by a column. The parameter is supposed to be optional. I am using SQL Server Express

```
@sortBy VARHCAR(255) = ''


BEGIN

        SELECT * FROM Document
        ORDER BY
        CASE @sortBy
            WHEN 'documentId' THEN documentId
            WHEN 'documentName' THEN documentName
            WHEN 'dateCreated' THEN dateCreated
            WHEN 'dateLastAccessed' THEN dateLastAccessed
            ELSE documentName
        END;
END
```

I can create the procedure, but when I execute it I get the following message

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

dateCreated and dateLastAccessed are of type DATE, but I can't tell if they are culprit. Am I accidentally telling the DB to convert a date/time with this procedure? This is the first time that I have worked with optional parameters for stored procedures, so I may not be doing that right. Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I think you are telling it to sort by string but its date type and it tries to convert the date to string to be able to perform the sort.

Comment: The predicate of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what comes after `THEN` and `ELSE`) has to be the same type in SQL Server.  So your `CASE` expression does not make sense.  If you really want a completely dynamic `ORDER BY` clause, then I think you'll have to use dynamic SQL and build the query.

Comment: This is because a case expression can return only a single datatype. And by the precedence rules a datetime is higher than a varchar so everything will be implicitly converted to higher precedence and things like documentName are going to struggle with that. You would have to convert your datetime to a varchar. But be careful there because you can end up with interesting order because of the way dates are represented as varchar.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by

Comment: You can convert a datetime to char(8) / style 112 or char(10) / style 120, and these will both sort as strings in a logical and expected way. Converting an integer to a string, however, will lead to other problems, like `2` sorting after `12`. So your choices are (a) multiple `CASE` expressions or (b) dynamic SQL (e.g. `SET @sql = N'SELECT ... ORDER BY ' + QUOTENAME(@sortBy) + N';'`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Tim and Sean wrote in their comment, a case expression can only return a single data type.
When each of the options contains a different data type, SQL Server tries to implicitly convert all the data types to the higher precedence data type ([see the list here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)).

You can overcome this by using a slightly more cumbersome query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Document
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'documentId' THEN documentId END,
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'documentName' THEN documentName END,
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'dateCreated' THEN dateCreated END,
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'dateLastAccessed' THEN dateLastAccessed END;
```

Note that without specifying the `else` part, the `case` expression will return `null` - so that shouldn't effect the overall order of the records.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: The only downside to this approach over dynamic sql is that dynamic sql would allow the usage of non-clustered indexes instead of performing a sort within the query.

Answer (score 1):

First, dynamic ordering doesn't work for mixed data types. That is, if you have fields of different data types that you want to order by - such as varchars and date. You need to use CONVERT to convert the mismatched data type to the same data type as the others. Or you can use dynamic sql. Maybe it's easier :))

```
SELECT * FROM Document
        ORDER BY
        CASE @sortBy
            WHEN 'documentId' THEN documentId
            WHEN 'documentName' THEN documentName
            WHEN 'dateCreated' THEN CONVERT(DATE, dateCreated)
            WHEN 'dateLastAccessed' THEN CONVERT(DATE, dateLastAccessed)
            ELSE documentName
        END;
```